# How to make a time series with calendar weeks dates in R

Tags: r, calendar, time-series, zoo, week-number

i cant find solution on this problem:  i have a time serie by calandar weeks, The problem is it only contains calendar week numbers (1:52 or 53) per year. and so for every carlendar week i have a value. My data.frame "df" is like this:

```
calendar_week  calendar_year  number_of_hospitalisation
1              2004              0
2              2004              2
3              2004              3
4              2004              6
.              2004              8
.              2004              26
53             2004              30
1              2005              4
2              2005              9
.              .                 .
.              .                 .
.              .                 .
52             .                 .
Note : There is no missing data
```

Now i would like  create a weekly time serie with dates corresponding to the calendar weeks(1,2,3 ...) from year 2004 to 2012.

I tried this:

```
    # created a date vector (weekly date)

    td = seq(as.Date("2004/1/7"), as.Date("2012/12/31"), "week")

    # created the zoo object by combining the dates with numeric data "df"

    myts = zoo(x=df, order.by=td)
```

The problem is , doing it this way create a strictly regular evenly spaced time serie object but some calendar weeks are less than 7 days and others are 7 days and some years have 53 calendar weeks and others 52 calendar weeks. Is there another function which is recognizing irregularities in the calendar with regard to number of days in a calendar week?  thanks a lot.

Comment: you can run `seq` separately for every year, e.g. `do.call(c,lapply(2004:2012,function(year) seq(as.Date(paste0(year,"/1/7")), as.Date(paste0(year,"/12/31")), "week")))
`

Comment: Thanks @MaratTalipov, i tried your suggestion but unfortunately all years have 53 weeks, which is not what i'm going for. Many thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: I must be missing something. Could you give an example of "some calendar weeks are less than 7 days"?

Comment: maybe you can try using the `ISOweek` package, if `df` is your data, does `ISOweek2date(paste0(df$calendar_year,"-W",sprintf("%02d",df$calendar_week),"-1"))` give you what you expect?

Comment: It uses the ISO8601 convention which is: "Week of the year as decimal number as defined in ISO 8601. If the week (starting on Monday) containing 1 January has four or more days in the new year, then it is considered week 1. Otherwise, it is the last week of the previous year, and the next week is week 1."

Comment: 7 does not divide evenly into 365 or 366 so you have a fundamental problem that needs to be resolved first.  Perhaps you could just use number of weeks since the beginning of the series as the index:  `zoo(df$number)` or another possibility is to use dates, e.g. `zoo(df$number, as.Date("2012-01-01") + 7*1:nrow(df) - 1)`

Comment: `ISOweek2date(paste0(df$calendar_year,"-W",sprintf("%02d",df$calendar_week),"-1"‌​))` actually did what i was expecting. So thanks very much for your help. Also i would like to thank you all for answering my question. Bests